# Prove that for $(m, n) = 1$, $b \mid m, c \mid n$, $(bc, mn/(bc)) = (b, m/b)(c, n/c)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am having trouble writing a clear proof that for $(m, n) = 1$, $b \mid m, c \mid n$, $(bc, mn/(bc)) = (b, m/b)(c, n/c)$. It makes complete sense in my head and I can kind of explain it in speech in a way that might convince someone that it is true, but I'd appreciate some help proving this in a clear and succinct manner. I start with the fact that $(b, c) = 1$ so any divisor will be of the form $xy$ where $x \mid b, y \mid c, (x, y) = 1$ and similarly for $mn/(bc)$. At this point it is already sort of clear in my head that the result follows, but when I try to put it in words it ends up sounding confusing and sloppy.

Comment: Note also that $(b,n/c)=1$ and $(c, m/b)=1$.

Comment: Yes, and so $x$ can only possibly divide $m/b$ (that is it can only be as large as any divisor of $m/b$), and a similar thing for $y$. Is this really enough to conclude though? I'm just worried that someone reading the proof would not be completely convinced.